# Git can't connect to Gitlab, SSH verification error

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've been trying to pull down a repository from Gitlab using SSH keys. All done in command line on Windows 8 via a Ubuntu VM. I've added my public key to my Gitlab account and then added my private key to the ssh-agent and didn't seem to have any errors in doing so but when I try and do a git pull or push I run in to this error;

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.mgmt.local/XXX/project-name.git/': 
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

And that's run me straight in to a wall ... no idea on what's wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using an https url.

Https means the public and private ssh keys stored in %HOME%.ssh are *not* used. At all.

Try switching to an ssh url:

```
git remote set-url origin (user)@(ip address):(group)/(project).git
```

With a standard GitLab installation `(user)` should be `git`.

You can check first if ssh is working with:

```
ssh -Tvvv git@your_server.com
```

Comment: ssh -Tvvv git@your_server.com is very helpful if you want to test if ssh works. Thanks.