# Git looking for my SSH key in the wrong location

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I've been having a bit of a head ache with trying to pull down a repository held in Gitlab. This is all done in Windows 8.1 on a Ubuntu VM by the way if that helps. I've added my public key in Gitlab and added my private key to ssh-agent ... all seems correct.

When I try and do a git pull this is where I run in to issues. It seems to me that Git is simply looking in the wrong location, my private key is stored in c/Users/Neil/.ssh but it seems as if git is looking in c/Users/Neil/.ssh/342/200/217 ...

```
C:\Users\Neil\code\homestead>git pull
no such identity: /c/Users/Neil/.ssh/id_rsa\342\200\217: No such file or directory
git@git.mgmt.local's password:
```

I've no idea why git would be looking there or am I thinking wrong about this? Can anyone shed some light on things for me?

Comment: Did you generated ssh keys from within the VM ? 
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: No I didn't, I used a putty keygen, that shouldn't matter should it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitLab itself isn't looking for your ssh keys: as a client, you are using ssh to contact GitLab, which means only openssh is looking for those keys.

It (openssh) will find them in:

- `%HOME%\.ssh` (so check what the environment variable `HOME` is set to)
- `%HOME%\.ssh\config` (where an IdentifiyFile directive can set a custom path for the ssh private key, so check if you have a `.ssh/config` file)

The [OP Neil Kelsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4617945/neil-kelsey) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784883/git-looking-for-my-ssh-key-in-the-wrong-location/28785821?noredirect=1#comment45850935_28785821) that the `%HOME%\.ssh\config` was causing some kind of interference.

And the push url seemed still referencing an https url.
A simple `git remote set-url --push origin <ssh/url>` fixed that.

Comment: So I have checked that my home directory is set to correct location which it is to find the keys in the correct folder %HOME%/.ssh and in that folder I do have a config file which I believe reads correctly

My host file reads as;

    Host git.mgmt.local
        Hostname git.mgmt.local
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa‏

And there is also a private key saved at that location by the name 'id_rsa'

Comment: @NeilKelsey can you try *without* the config file? If you are using a full ssh url, you shouldn't need the config file, especially when the public and private ssh keys have their default names (`id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` in `%HOME%\.ssh`)

Comment: Expanding on that ... I opened up a git bash terminal from c/users on my Windows machine and in that terminal typed '$echo $HOME' which gave me what I consider to be the correct result of 'c/Users/Neil' ... in that folder there is my .ssh folder which contains my config file and keys

Comment: @NeilKelsey ok, I like a simple cmd session myself, opened with https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat

Comment: I think removing the config file has resolved my issues! I seem to be able to pull down just fine, I can add and commit but I can't yet push back up ... trying to seems to use the http protocol again as per my previous problem. But getting close here!

Comment: @NeilKelsey what `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: The fetch URL is correct but the push URL is http ... I just need to figure out how to change change that to ssh and then I'm there!

Comment: @NeilKelsey strange: the `git remote set-url origin (user)@(ip address):(group)/(project).git` I recommended in my previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28783138/6309) should have changed *both* pull and push url.

Comment: @NeilKelsey you can change just the push url with a `git remote set-url --push origin ...`.

Comment: That's done it! I set the remote url using git remote set-url --push origin ...... checked it with git remote -v and sure enough that changes the URL, did a quick test and sure enough my push has made it up

Comment: Just ran into this with moving portable git around on disk.  The paths to the ssh keys are fully qualified paths in the ssh config.  Easy enough to edit in vim.  I just needed to realize that the .ssh directory had a config file of its own that was actually being used (makes sense) and, more importantly, had fully qualified paths in it (which makes less sense given that the software is called portable git).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS users, this problem can be fixed by running the following commands:

```sh
rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts # remove previous hosts
ssh-add -A # add all known SSH keys
```

After running the above commands, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: "`sudo rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`" Why use `sudo` for a file in `~/`?

Comment: Underrated comment. Also, no need to run `rm` if you don't want to remove existing keys. You can simply do `ssh-add -A`

Comment: so, does the second step regenerate ```~/.ssh/known_hosts```?