# Bitbucket Permission denied (publickey). but works with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, key, bitbucket, public

**Hello, if i try to connect with bitbucket.org using ssh**

```
ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
```

**Everything works fine**

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

**But if i try to use the `git clone` command i recive this message:**

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**Some extra information:**

- I already included the public key in my Bitbucket account
- I have the keys located in `~/.ssh/`
- I am not running with sudo
- The command `ssh-add -l` returns the correct key. (RSA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make this work, but there was multiple problems with my git implementation:

- I was trying to access a **organization** repository but i added the public key to my main account.
- I was trying to use `git clone` with the pattern USER@bitbucket.org, after trying with **git**@bitbucket.org everything worked.

I hope this helps someone with the same problem i had.

Answer (score 5):

I found similiar problem and the solution is here

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html

I just added two properties, `IdentitiesOnly` and `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` in ssh config.

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_bitbucket
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

Please note that there is security concern regarding this solution as mentioned in the link above

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me more for this exact problem, than the accepted answer: [Git looking for my SSH key in the wrong location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784883/git-looking-for-my-ssh-key-in-the-wrong-location)

Comment: In Windows, at least in my case, git and ssh were looking for id_rsa in two different folders, C:User\username\.ssh\ and F:\.ssh\, so it was enough to remap F properly

Answer (score 0):

Start the ssh agent if it is not set up to run automatically by running following command on powershell (run as administrator)

Start-Service ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

The example mentioned in atlassian support site was using Ed25519 key with 4096 bits. I could resolve this permission denied(publickey) by switching to **RSA**.

Generate the ssh key as -
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C someone@email.com`